# Провера юзера на онлайн yii2

Tags: yii2

Я хочу, чтобы один пользователь не смог логинить с двух или более браузеров, устройств и тп. Если юзер уже онлайн, то выходила ошибка.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if($user->isOnline()) {
echo 'user is online';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

В Yii2 правильно писать

```
Yii::$app->user->getIsGuest(); // возвращает тип bool
```

или

```
Yii::$app->user->isGuest; // возвращает тип bool
```

Comment: Почему "правильно" и как гостевой флаг относится к теме вопроса?